# How do I scrape an item that has same <span class> as other items?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, scrapy

So I'm getting this recurrent problem where I want to scrape an item on a web page but it turns out that this specific item has the same **span class** as other items. How can I guide the spider to the right **span class**?

See an example below. Let's say I want to scrape '105 m²'. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You have to figure out some invariant property of the item you want to scrape. If the class name is not unique, then use something else, for example the fixed index in the list (assuming that does not vary between the pages you want to scrape).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the information that the containing `li` is third among its siblings, and select the `span` using that:

```
ul.card-property__features > li:nth-child(3) > span.label__property
```

Reference: [nth-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: I tried to incorporate this in my line of code but it doesn't work.

Comment: `for l in response.css('div.ev-teaser-content'):`  
`yield {'area': l.css('ul.card-property__features > li:nth-child(3) > span.label__property::text').extract()}`

Comment: @fg42 I'm not sure if `nth-child` is supported in the library you're using. Can you try incrementally narrowing down the selector? For instance, does this work `ul.card-property__features > li:nth-child(3)`?